# Woocommerce, How to edit the “added to cart” message and implement notification system

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

As a title, my goal is to customize the Woocommerce notation system when a user puts a product in the shopping cart.

I searched the portal and I found the answer of a really perfect user, that is, for the modification of the message just go to insert this code in the `functions.php`

Code:

```
add_filter ( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'wc_add_to_cart_message_filter', 10, 2 );
function wc_add_to_cart_message_filter($message, $product_id = null) {
    $titles[] = get_the_title( $product_id );

    $titles = array_filter( $titles );
    $added_text = sprintf( _n( '%s has been added to your cart.', '%s have been added to your cart.', sizeof( $titles ), 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );

    $message = sprintf( '%s <a href="%s" class="button">%s</a>&nbsp;<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a>',
                    esc_html( $added_text ),
                    esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ) ),
                    esc_html__( 'Checkout', 'woocommerce' ),
                    esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ),
                    esc_html__( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ));

    return $message;
}
```

My intent was to implement a notification system using MDBootstrap toast
link:

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/javascript/notifications/

basically the guide makes available for the implementation of this notification system a js code and an html:

js:

```
$('.toast').toast('show');
```

html:

```
<div role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" class="toast" data-autohide="false">
  <div class="toast-header">
    <svg class=" rounded mr-2" width="20" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img">
      <rect fill="#007aff" width="100%" height="100%" /></svg>
    <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
    <small>11 mins ago</small>
    <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-body">
    Hello, world! This is a toast message.
  </div>
</div>
```

I automatically combined the user's answer in the link of my question plus this code inside the `functions.php` but I get an error and I can not figure out how it can make it work.

My Code in `functions.php`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.toast').toast('show');
</script>
<?php

add_filter ( 'wc_add_to_cart_message', 'wc_add_to_cart_message_filter', 10, 2 );
function wc_add_to_cart_message_filter($message, $product_id = null) {
    $titles[] = get_the_title( $product_id );

    $titles = array_filter( $titles );
    $added_text = sprintf( _n( '

<div role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true" class="toast" data-autohide="false">
  <div class="toast-header">
    <svg class=" rounded mr-2" width="20" height="20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img">
      <rect fill="#007aff" width="100%" height="100%" /></svg>
    <strong class="mr-auto">Bootstrap</strong>
    <small>11 mins ago</small>
    <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="toast-body">

        %s has been added to your cart.', '%s have been added to your cart

  </div>
</div>.', sizeof( $titles ), 'woocommerce' ), wc_format_list_of_items( $titles ) );

    $message = sprintf( '%s <a href="%s" class="button">%s</a>&nbsp;<a href="%s" class="button">%s</a>',
                    esc_html( $added_text ),
                    esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ) ),
                    esc_html__( 'Checkout', 'woocommerce' ),
                    esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ) ),
                    esc_html__( 'View Cart', 'woocommerce' ));

    return $message;
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WooCommerce version?

Comment: @MujeebuRahman 3.5.4

Comment: The new filter - https://gist.github.com/JeroenSormani/e53dacc267f5beccdc0962cfb16dba3d#file-added-to-cart-notice-woocommerce-php

Answer (score 1):

Rather than implementing your own toast notification feature, I suggest you use this light and simple [ToastMaker](https://github.com/vivekweb2013/toastmaker) library which is very much customisable & only **1KB** in size.

```js
$('#mybutton').click(()=>{ToastMaker("This is a toast notification!")});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/toastmaker/dist/toastmaker.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/toastmaker/dist/toastmaker.min.js"></script>


<button id="mybutton">Show Toast</button>
```

### Visit [this page](https://toastmaker.wirehall.com/) to check more examples with beautiful styled toast messages